# How to Properly Increment Static Variable?

Tags: java, methods, static

Here is the method in the driver:

```
public class CustomerTest {

    private static int customerCounter = 0;

    public static boolean test1(){
        System.out.println("Test1: create a customer");
        Customer c = new Customer("Alice", "Smith");
        customerCounter++;
        return c.getName().equals("Alice Smith") && customerCounter == c.getCustomerID();
    }

    public static boolean test2() {
        System.out.println("Test2: create two customers");
        Customer c1 = new Customer("Alice", "Smith");
        Customer c2 = new Customer("Bob", "Simpson");
        customerCounter += 2;
        return c1.getName().equals("Alice Smith") && (customerCounter - 1) == c1.getCustomerID()
        && c2.getName().equals("Bob Simpson") && (customerCounter) == c2.getCustomerID();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result = "";
        //System.out.print("Test 1: ");
        result = test1() ? "pass." : "failed.";
        System.out.println(result);
                //System.out.print("Test 2: ");
        result = test2() ? "pass." : "failed.";
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Here is code I've written:

```
public class Customer {

    public static final int MAX_ACCOUNTS = 5;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int customerID;
    private BankAccount[] accounts;
    private int numAccounts;
    private static int nextCustomerID = 1;

    //default constructor
    public Customer() {
        firstName = "";
        lastName = "";
        customerID = 1;
        accounts = null;
        numAccounts = 0;
        nextCustomerID = 1;
    }

    //Constructor sets name and initialized values
    //@param first is the first name
    //@param last is the last name
    public Customer (String first, String last)
    {
        this.firstName = first;
        this.lastName = last;
        this.customerID = 1;
        Customer.nextCustomerID = 1;

    }    

    public String getFirst(){
        return firstName;

    }
    public String getLast(){
        return lastName;
    }


    public String getName ()
    {
        return String.format("%s,%s", getFirst(),getLast());

    }
    public int getCustomerID ()
    {
        return customerID;

    }

}
```

When I run the driver it returns failed for test 2.I think its because I am improperly incrementing my nextCustomerID.

Comment: FYI, you may want to look into JUnit if you're looking to right tests for your  code. That's the standard for Java unit testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never increment `nextCustomerId`. It's a private variable, so it can only change within `Customer`, and the only place you reference it is to assign it the value 1.

The following two lines of your constructor are incorrect:

```
this.customerID = 1;
Customer.nextCustomerID = 1;
```

Replace these with:

```
this.customerID = nextCustomerId;
nextCustomerID++;
```

(You should also update your default constructor in a similar fashion).

The `++` operator increments the variable's value by `1`.

The `=` operator is a simple assignment operator, and simply sets the variable on the left-hand side to the value on the right-hand side.

It'll be worthwhile to review the [Java Introduction to Assignment and Unary operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html).

Answer (score 1):

But you are not even using `nextCustomerID`

If you were to do something like

```
public Customer (String first, String last)
{
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    Customer.nextCustomerID += 1;
    this.customerID = Customer.nextCustomerID;

}
```

then I believe you tests would work

**Edit**

Change the start value of nextCustomerID to be zero

or change

```
    this.customerID = Customer.nextCustomerID;
    Customer.nextCustomerID += 1;
```

Comment: now test 1 and 2 fail, whereas before test 1 passed and test 2 failed.

Comment: Change the start value of `nextCustomerID` to be zero - have a look at my edit

Comment: @MiloStaKic How did your tests work if your names are never matching?

Comment: Thrasher, which names? there shouldn't be a comma inbetween %s %s

Answer (score 0):

### Problems:

1) nextCustomerID is not incrementing

2) the name are not matching because your getName function has a comma.

So:

### Customer (constructors):

```
    //default constructor
    public Customer() {
        firstName = "";
        lastName = "";
        customerID = 1;
        accounts = null;
        numAccounts = 0;
        Customer.nextCustomerID += 1;
        this.customerID = Customer.nextCustomerID;
    }

    //Constructor sets name and initialized values
    //@param first is the first name
    //@param last is the last name
    public Customer (String first, String last)
    {
        this.firstName = first;
        this.lastName = last;
        Customer.nextCustomerID += 1;
        this.customerID = Customer.nextCustomerID;

    }
```

### CustomerTest:

```
public class CustomerTest {

    private static int customerCounter = 1;

    public static boolean test1(){
        System.out.println("Test1: create a customer");
        Customer c = new Customer("Alice", "Smith");
        customerCounter++;
        return c.getName().equals("Alice,Smith") && customerCounter == c.getCustomerID();
    }

    public static boolean test2() {
        System.out.println("Test2: create two customers");
        Customer c1 = new Customer("Alice", "Smith");
        Customer c2 = new Customer("Bob", "Simpson");
        customerCounter += 2;
        System.out.println ( c1.getName ( ) +" " + c2.getName ( ) );
        return c1.getName().equals("Alice,Smith") && (customerCounter - 1) == c1.getCustomerID()
        && c2.getName().equals("Bob,Simpson") && (customerCounter) == c2.getCustomerID();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result = "";
        //System.out.print("Test 1: ");
        result = test1() ? "pass." : "failed.";
        System.out.println(result);
                //System.out.print("Test 2: ");
        result = test2() ? "pass." : "failed.";
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```